# Passing string "classValue" from a C# Class to a C# form string "formValue"

Tags: c#, string, class, parameter-passing, argument-passing

I would like to complete a command in C# using a class called `GenerateKeys` inside the class there is a function called `GenKeyA(classValue);` this is called from the default `button1_click` event handler in Visual Studio 13, using the form string variable `formValue` like so. `GenKeyA(formValue)`, and by doing this i would like to send that returned string to a `textBox1.Text` variable. Please correct me if im wrong in any way!.

```
public class GenerateKeys
/// The Class
{
    /// string Variable.
    string classValue = "";
    /// Called from button1_click

    private void GenKeyA (string classValue)
    {
          Random rand = new Random();
          classValue = ""+rand.Next(0,9)+""+rand.Next(0,9)+""+rand.Next(0,9)+"";

          /// from here, i wish to return the string classValue to 
          /// the form1.frmValue string then send that to textBox1.Text = formValue;
    }

}
```

Comment: What problems are you having? you need to change the return type of `GenKeyA`, presumably to `string`

Comment: i wish to use a class for a function, and in that function, i would like to create a string that can be passed back through that class and function into the main forms variable string, and then pass that to a textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return a value to another class from a method, you only need to do three things:

1. Make it public, so the other class can 'see' it.
2. Add a return type to your method (other than `void`, which means it doesn't return)
3. Use the keyword `return` to pass an object back to the caller.

So, you can change your method like this:

```
public string GenKeyA (string classValue)
{
    Random rand = new Random();

    return rand.Next(0,9).ToString() + rand.Next(0,9).ToString() + 
        rand.Next(0,9).ToString();    
}
```

Then, on the calling side, you would do something like:

```
textBox1.Text = GenKeyA(someStringValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make the function return a `string` and be `public` (or `internal` depending on your setup):

```
public string GenKeyA (string classValue)
```

Then call it in your form by doing:

```
form1.frmValue = GenKeyA(classValue);
textBox1.Text = formValue;
```